# How to set up webpack custom entry and output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm learning webpack 4. Is there a way to set custom entry and output, because no tutorial seems to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following link:

https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/#webpack_4_overriding_the_defaults_entryoutput

**Quote from the link:**

> I love webpack 4 zero conf but how about overriding the default entry point? And the default output?
>
> Configure them in package.json!

**An example from the link:**

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack --mode development ./foo/src/js/index.js --output ./foo/main.js",
  "build": "webpack --mode production ./foo/src/js/index.js --output ./foo/main.js"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure entry and output in [webpack.config.js](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/). In example configuration below I have added [entry](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry) as a `string` whereas you can add as an `object` and `array` as well and in a similar way you can add [output](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) key as a string, as follows:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './app/main.js',
    cache: true,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './resources/script.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Below is the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) to work with `npm` dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React Js",
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "Arpit Aggarwal",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch -d"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0"
  }
}
```